# sortByKey() by composite key in PySpark

Tags: pyspark, rdd

In an RDD with composite key, is it possible to sort in ascending order with the first element and in descending order with the second order when both of them are string type? I have provided some dummy data below.

```
 z = [(('a','b'), 3), (('a','c'), -2), (('d','b'), 4), (('e','b'), 6), (('a','g'), 8)]  

rdd = sc.parallelize(z)

rdd.sortByKey(False).collect()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe there's more efficient way, but here is one:

```py
str_to_ints = lambda s, i: [ord(c) * i for c in s]
rdd.sortByKey(keyfunc=lambda x: (str_to_ints(x[0], 1), str_to_ints(x[1], -1))).collect()
# [(('a', 'g'), 8), (('a', 'c'), -2), (('a', 'b'), 3), (('d', 'b'), 4), (('e', 'b'), 6)]
```

Basically convert the strings in the key to list of integers with first element multiplied by **1** and second element multiplied by **-1**.